# How to view a longer code revision history in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, repository, revision-history

To view historical code revisions/deletions/changes (etc), we right click a .java file in Package Exlorer and go `Replace With -> Local History`. This shows the revisions over the last two days. How do I get a more complete history of revisions?

Note I know about SVN.

Answer (score 3):

The local history is configured in `Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History`. You can increase the number of days history is kept for there (but this only starts working from the time you set it).

Rather than just relying on the local history using a source control system like SVN or GIT gives you complete history.

Comment: So everything that's not displayed in the `ReplaceWith -> LocalHistory` is permanently gone?

Comment: @user2763361 Yes it is gone. Unless you have backups.